# PHP MongoDB Driver on shared hosting doesnt connect to atlas

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb, mongodb-atlas

Connecting to the mongodb atlas free tier from a sharedhosting using mongodb driver 1.5.2 and trying to write a simple document gives the following error. What am I doing wrong?

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://admin:admin@test-shard-00-00-rbgc.mongodb.net:27017/db?ssl=false&replicaSet=test-shard-0&authSource=admin&serverSelectionTryOnce=false");

var_dump($manager);

$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

$bulk->insert(['x' => 1]);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.collection', $bulk);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable
>   servers found: serverselectiontimeoutms timed out: [connection closed
>   calling ismaster on 'test-shard-00-00-waf4c.mongodb.net:27017'] in
>   /Applications/AMPPS/www/mongodb/liveserver.php:63

When I var_dump the $manager I get:

> object(MongoDB\Driver\Manager)#1 (2) { ["uri"]=> string(64)
>   "admin:admin@test-shard-00-00-rbgc.mongodb.net:27017/" ["cluster"]=>
>   array(0) { } }

I have also tried the following but the errors keeps being the same:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://admin:admin@pirat-shard-00-00-vegbq.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/db?ssl=falseweak_cert_validation=false');

$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;


$bulk->insert(['x' => 1]);
$bulk->insert(['x' => 2]);
$bulk->insert(['x' => 3]);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.collection2', $bulk);
```

Comment: Can you connect to it from anywhere else? `telnet test-shard-00-00-rbgc.mongodb.net 27017` says "nodename nor servname provided, or not known"

Comment: @AlexBlex I can connect to it from my local machine which doesnt use OpenSSL in the mongoDB or  libcrypto  but instead it uses Secure Transport  and Common Crypto .

Comment: You aren't using ssl - it is `ssl=false` in the url, yes?  Try to follow http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php and split the connection string to match the constructor interface.

Comment: @AlexBlex I tried it with ssl=true also but I get the same results sadly. :(

Comment: Have you tried to create the manager with parameters it expects?

Comment: @AlexBlex can you please elaborate on what you mean? I have tried some of the parameters in http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php

Comment: What do you mean by "some"? There are only 3, and you use only 1st in the question putting everything as a single string. If you tried anything else, please update the question with your attempts.

Comment: @AlexBlex I have updated my question with the latest test I did and still get the same error. I dont understand how to use the other parameters, could you please enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection string is wrong. There are 2 versions for new and legacy drivers, both versions are provided by atlas:

[image]

The 3.6+ version should be:

```
mongodb+srv://admin:admin@test-shard-rbgc.mongodb.net:27017/db?retryWrites=true
```

It's `mongodb+srv://` and a single address of the shard with little parameters. It should work with mongodb-1.5. If not, try the legacy one:

The 3.4- version should be (a single line):

```
mongodb://admin:admin@test-shard-00-00-rbgc.mongodb.net:27017,
   test-shard-00-01-rbgc.mongodb.net:27017,
   test-shard-00-02-rbgc.mongodb.net:27017
   /db?ssl=true&replicaSet=Test-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true
```

It's `mongodb://`, list of all members of the replica set in the url, name of the replicaset in the parameter etc.

Also, ensure your server's IP address is whitelisted in the atlas.

Comment: This code and the original in question work fine with MongoDB Compass, only problem is that it doesnt work when trying to connect through the mongodb PHP driver, which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: I have also already whitelisted all IPs so no error can be from that.

Comment: Just tested on Ubuntu Bionic with stock php 7.2.10 and mongodb 1.3.4 the legacy connection works.

Comment: upgraded mongodb driver to 1.5.3 - it perfectly works with new v3.6 connection url.

Comment: There is the image `docker pull alexblex/so-52627401` if you want to check other settings.

Comment: Its probalby the shared host invironment. I will look into a docker solution, thank you for your help.

Comment: Fair enough. Try to contact hosting support. Please clean your collection2 and change passwords. I'm afraid I did few inserts there testing it.

Comment: No problem, I think it has something to do with OpenSSL is your mongodb module in phpinfo() using OpenSSL?

Comment: I think so, you can pull the image to check. It's the purpose of publishing it. I definitely was using `ssl=true` in the legacy url.

Comment: Funny thing is I dont know how to use Docker :( 
Thats why I asked about the phpinfo() of mongodb module (>_<)

Comment: fair enough. It was `libmongoc SSL => enabled;
libmongoc SSL library => OpenSSL;
OpenSSL support => enabled;
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017`